# suggesting a new name for Image file & save it with PIL img.save()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Is there any way to suggest a new name or get a string supplied from the commandline like: `./py_module.py <img_file> <new_file_name>`

```
.
.
.
new_img     = img.resize((horz_rsz, w_input), Image.ADAPTIVE)
name_input  = input("suggest a name: ") // or sys.argv[2]
print(im_width, im_height, wh_ratio, horz_rsz, new_img.size)

new_img.save(name_input+'', 'png')
```

I'm getting error because the **.save()** function for an image searches for that name if it's defined in program scope.

so, is this possible?

errors:

> height to resize: 500
>   suggest a name: abc
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "img_resize.py", line 17, in 
>   name_input  = input("suggest a name: ")
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'abc' is not defined

Comment: Can you paste the error into your post?

Comment: @RandomDavis: check it again

Comment: You are apparently using Python 2.x, in which case you should be using `raw_input()` instead of `input()` (which reads Python expressions in those versions, not strings).

Comment: @jasonharper: thanks!